# Issue in docker compose with volume undefined

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I get the below error when I run docker-compose up, any pointers why I am getting this error

> service "mysqldb-docker" refers to undefined volume mysqldb: invalid compose project

Also, is there a way to pass the $ENV value in CLI to docker-compose up , currently I have a ENV variable that specified dev, uat or prod that I use to specify the db name. Are there better alternatives to do this other than create a .env file explicitly for this

```
 version: '3.8'
    services:
      mysqldb-docker:
        image: '8.0.27'
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        ports:
          - "3309:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=reco-tracker-$ENV
        volumes:
          - mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql
      reco-tracker-docker:
        image: 'reco-tracker-docker:v1'
        ports:
          - "8083:8083"
        environment:
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-docker:3309/reco-tracker-$ENV"
        depends_on: [mysqldb-docker]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must define `volumes` at the top level like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysqldb-docker:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysqldb:
```

Comment: How about volume created before the docker-compose.yml file. Also, do we need to specify "/var/lib/mysql" at the top level as well

Answer (score 0):

You can pass environment variables from your shell straight through to a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key by not giving them a value

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers

```
web:
  environment:
    - ENV
```

but from my tests you cant write $ENV in the compose file and expect it to read your env

for this you need to call docker-compose that way :

```
docker-compose run -e ENV web python console.py
```

see this : https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `mysqldb` volume already created, check if exists with `docker volume ls`

If not, you can create it with `docker volume create mysqldb`

You can reference it, as follows:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysqldb-docker:
    volumes:
      - mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysqldb:
    external: true
```